# In Laymen's terms, what is Redis Pub/Sub?

Tags: redis, publish-subscribe

Why would I use it?
Give some very basic examples.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A redis client *subscribes* to receive messages marked with a specific tag, termed *channel*.  Other clients *publish* to this channel.  Redis notifies each subscribing client each time a message is published by anyone to the channel.

You can also subscribe to a channel pattern - think regex matching.

This helps make code ***distributable***.  It allows bits of code to run in different processes, and potentially even different machines, and to communicate with each other via these queues.

This feature comes from [repeated user requests](http://antirez.com/post/redis-weekly-update-3-publish-submit.html).  There is an example use-case given [here](http://blog.mjrusso.com/2010/10/17/redis-from-the-ground-up.html):

> a news-related site needs to update
>   the cached copy of its home page every
>   time that a new article is published.
>
> The background cache worker process
>   subscribes to all channels that begin
>   with ‘new.article.’:
>
> ```
> redis> PSUBSCRIBE new.article.*
> ```
>
> The article publishing process creates
>   a new technology article (in this
>   example, this article has ID ‘1021’),
>   adds the article’s ID to the set of
>   all technology articles, and publishes
>   the article’s ID to the
>   ‘new.article.technology’ channel:
>
> ```
> redis> MULTI
> OK
> redis> SET article.technology.1021 "In today's technology news, ..."
> QUEUED
> redis> SADD article.technology 1021
> QUEUED
> redis> PUBLISH new.article.technology 1021
> QUEUED
> redis> EXEC
> 1. OK
> 2. (integer) 1
> 3. (integer) 1
> ```
>
> At this point, the background cache
>   worker process will receive a message
>   and know immediately that a new
>   technology article was published,
>   subsequently executing the appropriate
>   callback to re-generate the home page.

http://redis.io/topics/pubsub